# Find a closed form of $a_n$ where $na_n=2(n - 1) + (n + 1)a_{n - 1}$ and $a_1 = a_0 = 0$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have tried to substitute $n$ with $n - 1$ to get $$(n - 1)a_{n - 1} = 2(n - 2) + na_{n - 2}$$
and then combine the two equations to get
$$n(a_n - 2a_{n - 1} + a_{n - 2})=2$$
but this didn't lead me anywhere.

I heard there is a method to solve such non-homogenous equations by finding a solution to the homogeneous equation and finding a particular solution to the non-homogeneous one. I know how to solve the homogenous equation, but I don't know how to find a particular solution or don't know this method in detail.

If anyone can help solve this recurrence or recommend a good explanatory source where I can learn how to solve such recurrences, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for "variation of parameters".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the recurrence as:
$$
na_n-(n+1)a_{n-1}=2(n-1)\ .
$$
Now multiply through by $\ \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\ $,
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{(n+1)}-\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}&=\frac{2(n-1)}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{-2}{n}+\frac{4}{n+1}\ ,
\end{align}
and sum both sides of this identity from $\ n=1\ $ to $\ m\ $ to get
\begin{align}
\frac{a_m}{m+1}&=-2\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n}+4\sum_{n=2}^{m+1}\frac{1}{n}\\
&=-4+\frac{4}{m+1}+2\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}\ .
\end{align}
Finally, multiply this equation through by $\ m+1\ $ to get
$$
a_m=-4m+2(m+1)\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}\ .
$$
I doubt if there's any simpler formula for the general term of the recurrence, since  none is known for the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), $\ H_n=\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\ $.

Comment: Thanks for help! Very elegant.